# why Dispatcher.invoke() not working?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

whenever a change is occured changes i call this set_filelist_inventory(). and send a new list to this function but UI is not upadating.

```
public partial class Inventory : UserControl
{
    public List<String> file_list = new List<String>();
    public void set_filelist_inventory(List<string> x)
     {
        if (file_list.SequenceEqual(x)) { }
        else
        {
            file_list = x;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                listview1.ItemsSource = file_list;
            });
        }
    }

    public Inventory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        file_list = General.GetFileList();
        Discover d = new Discover();
        d.send(d);
        listview1.ItemsSource = file_list;

    }

}
```

I tried removing if else block. it still didn't worked.

Comment: Do you need the Invoke call for any specific reason?

Comment: @Clemens  i need to update my UI containers as soon as my filelist changes.

Comment: You would only need Invoke when you call set_filelist_inventory from a different thread (which is not the UI thread).

Comment: do you debug the code without exceptions? , your code should work

Comment: This is just a guess, but you should try to change the file_list instead of "resetting" it to x. Try clearing the list and adding a new element (file_list.add(...)) for each item in x. Might work ^^

Comment: @Clemens yes i have thredpool which is fetching filelist and doing other things while my UI thred is doing other task.

Comment: You actually getting an exception or blank on UI ?? Whats going on